# Can logarithmic connection operate on currents?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a compact Kähler manifold of dimension $n$, and let $D=\sum_{i=1}^r D_i$ be a simple normal crossing divisor on it, i.e., a divisor with smooth components $D_i$ intersecting each other transversally in $X$.
Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a locally free coherent sheaf on $X$ and let
$$\nabla:\mathcal{V}\to \Omega^1_X(\log D)\otimes\mathcal{V}$$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map satisfying
\begin{align}\nabla(f\cdot e)=f\cdot\nabla e+df\otimes e.\end{align}
One defines
$$\nabla_a:\Omega^a_X(\log D)\otimes \mathcal{V}\to \Omega^{a+1}_X(\log D)\otimes \mathcal{V}$$
by the rule
$$\nabla_a (\omega\otimes e)=d\omega\otimes e+(-1)^a \omega\wedge \nabla e.$$
We assume that $\nabla_{a+1}\circ\nabla_a=0$ for all $a$. Such $\nabla$ will be called **an integrable logarithmic connection along $D$, or just a connection.**
When $\omega\in A^{0,q}(\Omega_X^p(\log D))$, by taking $\diamondsuit=\nabla+\bar{\partial}_\mathcal{V}$, we have
$$\nabla(\omega\otimes e)=\partial\omega\otimes e+{(-1)}^{p+q}\omega\wedge\nabla(e),$$
$$\bar\partial_\mathcal{V}(\omega\otimes e)=\bar\partial\omega\otimes e.$$

---

According to Junjiro Noguchi, *A short analytic proof of closedness of logarithmic forms*, Kodai Math. J. 18, (1995), No. 2, 295-299, for any $\alpha\in A^{0,q}(X,\Omega^p_X(\log D)\otimes\mathcal V)$, there is a current  $T_\alpha\in \mathcal{D}'^{p,q}(X,\mathcal V)$ associated with it, which is defined by
$$
T_{\alpha}(\beta)=\int_X \alpha\wedge \beta,\quad \beta\in A^{n-p,n-q}(X,\mathcal V^*). $$

**Now my question is, can the logarithmic connection operate on $T_{\alpha}$? How?**

---

Here is my thought:

According to this post: [Can logarithmic connection on holomorphic vector bundle induce logarithmic connection on dual bundle?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363134/can-logarithmic-connection-on-holomorphic-vector-bundle-induce-logarithmic-conne) , now $\nabla\beta\in A^{0,n-q}(X,\Omega_X^{n-p}(\log D)\otimes \mathcal V^*)$, we define $\nabla T_\alpha\in\mathcal{D}'^{p+1,q}(X,\mathcal V)$ by the following rule:

$$\langle\nabla T_\alpha,\beta\rangle={(-1)}^{p+q+1}\langle T_\alpha,\nabla\beta\rangle={(-1)}^{p+q+1}\int_X \alpha\wedge\nabla\beta,\quad \text{for } \beta\in A^{n-p-1,n-q}(X,\mathcal V^*). $$

---

So is my method right? Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean action on the space of currents? Or currents which do come from differential forms by the formula you decribed? On all currents it is not possible, on differential form you will obtain a current yes.

Comment: @LevSoukhanov，I mean action on special currents those come from log forms, thanks for your help.

Comment: So you ask whether they act on logarithmic forms? They act, yes, indeed (if you mean log poles on the same divisor as the divisor of the logartihmic connection).

Comment: Dear @LevSoukhanov, I feel a little confused. I ask can $\nabla$ act on $T_\alpha$ then obtain a new current $\nabla T_\alpha$? Here, $T_\alpha$ come from $\alpha\in A^{0,q}(X,\Omega_X^p(\log D)\otimes\mathcal V)$. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: I do not understand why you insist on using currents. I think we can just try to make sense of $\nabla \alpha$ for any $\alpha \in A^{0,q}(X, \Omega_X^p(\text{log }D) \otimes \mathcal{V})$?

Comment: @LevSoukhanov, actually, I came across this problem when doing some relevant research, I just wanna make sense whether we can use $\nabla$ act on $\mathcal V$-valued current (coming from $\mathcal V$-valued log form)  instead of $\partial$ act on $(p,q)$-current.

Comment: I mean, lets do it in local coordinates near the point of the divisor $D$, divisor locally defined by equations $dx_i / x_i$, $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$.

Then, $\alpha = \underset{i_1 < ... < i_p, j_1 < ... < j_q}{\sum} \alpha_{i_1...i_p j_1 ... j_q} ds_{i_1} ... ds_{i_p} d\bar{x}_{j_1}... d\bar{x}_{j_q}$, where $s_i = dx_i/x_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$ and $= dx_i$ otherwise, and components of $\alpha$ are in $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: Then you just define the action of $\Diamond$, and it is very clear that it is well defined and gives a log form again, I hope it is clear how to define it from the coordinate notation.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your assistance and patience again.

Comment: Sure. I mean, $dx/x$ is a well defined current on $\mathbb{C}$ indeed; it is defined as integration in the sense of principal value. Then it is a very nice fact that $\bar{\partial} dx/x = 2\pi i dx \wedge d\bar{x} \delta(x, \bar{x})$ (prove it, it is very cool!), and from the algebraic construction above you won't have this.

So you, like, need to make a decision whether you want to define the action of $\Diamond$ on currents (the answer is yes and defined from this formula) or just action on log forms (i.e., regular part of the answer on currents, well defined too).